# If we have that $Cov(Y, X-Y) = 0$, does this imply $Y$ is independent of $X-Y$?

Tags: probability, independence, covariance

If we have that $Cov(Y, X-Y) = 0$, does this imply $Y$ is independent of $X-Y$ for random variables $X$ and $Y$? Intuition tells me that normally this is not true, but we have the variable $Y$ appear twice so I am not so sure. Could anyone lend me a hand here? thanks!

Comment: No, it only implies that $X$ and $Z := X-Y$ are uncorrelated, but not necessarily independent. Uncorrelated only means that $E[X(X-Y)] - E[X]E[X-Y] = 0$, while for independence we need $P(X=x, Z=z) - P(X = x)P(Z=z) = 0$. You could try plugging in Z = X-Y and play around with it maybe there is some more statements to be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that uncorrelated does not imply independence. Two notable exceptions:

1. They jointly follows a multivariate normal.
2. They both follow a Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: That is a confirmation of what the OP was thinking (in that sense a useful comment), but not really an answer to his question.

Comment: @drhab If $X$ is Bernoulli, can $X-Y$ be Bernoulli?

Comment: @BCLC Yes. For that you need $P(X=0\wedge Y=1)=0$.

Comment: @drhab Cmiiw, but then BGM does answer the question?

Answer (score 4):

Counterexample:

Let it be that $X=ZY$ for some non-degenerate random variable $Z$ s.t. $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

Then $Y$ and $X-Y=(Z-1)Y$ are not independent.

Also let it be that $\mathbb EZ=1$ and $\mathbb EY=0$, and consequently $\mathbb EX=\mathbb EY\mathbb EZ=0$.

Then $\mathbb EX=\mathbb EY\mathbb EZ=0$ and $\mathbb E(X-Y)=0$ so that:

$\text{Cov}(Y,X-Y)=\mathbb EY(X-Y)=\mathbb EY^2(Z-1)=\mathbb EY^2\mathbb E(Z-1)=0$

The last line under condition that $\mathbb EY^2<\infty$.